# Batch search a directory for multiple file names

Tags: excel, batch-file, filesystems, notepad++

I'll present the practical example first so you can understand what I'm doing. Please note this is on my work computer and network, so I do not have admin rights.

I have a list of items - about 1000 lines, currently in Excel. I normalized it a bit to remove characters that may or may not be included in a file referencing these items. I have access to a directory (via Windows Explorer or Sharepoint), that holds certain documents that may be associated to these items (if we have any information on them). This directory is organized as follows:

- A:

  - \A

    - \Armadillo

      - Armadillo.doc
    - \Army

      - Army.doc
  - \B

    - \Bull

      - Bull.doc

I'd like to run a batch search of some sort to find out if there is a file or directory name that matches a line of text, and then do that for the entire 1000 lines.

For example, say my file has the following lines of text:

```
Armadillo
Army
Baby
Bull
```

And assume the directory has files that match Armadillo, Army, and Bull, but not Baby.. I'd like the output to detail the file name and location, for example:

```
Armadillo     A:\A\Armadillo\Armadillo.doc
Army          A:\A\Army\Army.doc
Baby
Bull          A:\B\Bull\Bull.doc
...and so on for every line.
```

I only want to read the target directory and report the match (or no match) - no file modification whatsoever. I do not need to look into the actual files, only file names. I also do not want to do anything that could potentially alter the file system. I just want to automate a process that could take forever doing manually, line by line.

I'm sure there are a number of ways to do this with macros in Excel, Find in Files in Notepad++, grep, etc. I've spent numerous hours looking for a solution to this exact problem, but all the solutions seem to be trying to solve a similar problem, but not exact. I'm hoping there is an easy way to do this without altering the file system or causing significant load.

Comment: `I've spent numerous hours looking for a solution` What's not working?

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "delims=" %A in (filename.txt) do dir /s /b "c:\startingdir\%A" >> results.txt
```

See `for /?` and `dir /?` for help. `>>` means append out put to a file. In a batch file use `%%A` instead of `%A` when typing interactively.

`&` allows multiple commands.

```
for /f "delims=" %A in (filename.txt) do echo %A & dir /s /b "c:\startingdir\%A" >> results.txt
```

Comment: You need to add some wildcard characters to your DIR filemask.

Comment: Not in this as the file has filenames.

Comment: Your DIR will fail because Armadillo will not match Armadillo.doc. Also, you don't verify that Armadillo.doc is in a folder named Armadillo. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36262300/1012053)

Comment: He's got a file of filenames.

Comment: No he doesn't. Read the question more carefully. He expects Armadillo to match Armadillo\Armadillo.doc

Answer (score 0):

This does everything but align the file names. There are some subtle edge cases that could cause problems, such as "c:\startingdir\Armadillo\Armadillo.x\somefile", or "c:\sartingdir\Armadillo\Armadillo.x.txt". But I suspect this is good enough for your needs.

```
@echo off
for /f "useback eol=: delims=" %%D in ("file.txt") do (
  for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in (
    'dir /b /a-d /s "c:\startingdir\%%D.??????????????" 2^>nul^|findstr /li "\\%%D\\%%D."'
  ) do echo %%D   %%F
) || echo %%D
```